# how to replace add a comment text from facebook comments

Tags: html, facebook

I am using the facebook application, is there any way to replace the default text "add a comment" and "Post comment to my Facebook profile" from comments

Comment: Showing some code would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply,<iframe width="380px;" style="padding-top: 20px; height:600px;" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0" name="" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=&xid=" />

Comment: How this is PHP-related?

Answer (score 0):

No. Doing so would violate cross site security restrictions. Facebook has made its comment box so that it is THEIR comment box; you can NOT change their site's stuff.